# How to find support for specific package version in upcoming Ubuntu versions

Tags: release-management

If an user wanted to look for example, for a version of a specific package in a new version of Ubuntu, let's say, I want to know if Ubuntu 12.10 will have ALSA 1.0.26 or if it will have MESA 9.0. How will I go about looking for this information? What places can I check directly to search for this specific info?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your require information from [this](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) site. You can easily search in different Ubuntu version and get your desire information.